# Playframework dist does not support sub projects?

Tags: playframework-2.2

Currently on 2.2.1.  Ive got a play project with 2 play sub projects setup as shown on:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTSubProjects

I've got a main route file and routes files for each of the sub projects.

Routes:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
->      /app                        admin.Routes
->      /workflow                   workflow.Routes
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

admin.routes

```
GET /abcd  controllers.someController
```

When I do a play run, everything seems to work as expected.  I can hit the abcd controller via

```
/app/abcd
```

When I do a play dist, it seems like the routes file running is not from the top level play server but from one of the sub-projects and I only see routes from the admin subproject and the path is incorrect:

```
/abcd
```

Question is, does dist support sub projects?  If so, how do I debug whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It should support submodules.  There's a known issue related to sbt described here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/QavYYDJVdMI

But it should have been fixed.

You can look at the the version of sbt in your project like this:

```
<your-app-dir>/project$ cat build.properties
sbt.version=0.13.0
```